# How to approach this? If $2m^3 - 8m^2 + 8n^3 - 12n^2 -10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$, then $8m^3 - 12m^2 + 2n^3 - 8n^2 - 10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Assuming

$$2m^3 - 8m^2 + 8n^3 - 12n^2 -10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$

Prove

$$8m^3 - 12m^2 + 2n^3 - 8n^2 - 10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$$

---

**I tried the following:**

$$8m^3 - 12m^2 + 2n^3 - 8n^2 - 10 \equiv 6m^3 - 4m^2 - 6n^3 + 4n^2 \mod 10$$

I'm not sure where to go from here or even if this is correct.

Comment: I note that the sum of the two polynomials is zero (mod 10).

Comment: $\!\!\bmod 10:\ f_2 \equiv -f_1\equiv -0\equiv 0\ \ $

Comment: @EricTowers Wouldn't that be assuming what we want to prove, i.e. that $8m^3 - 12m^2 + 2n^3 - 8n^2 - 10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$ is true by adding the two polynomials? Nevermind, thanks for the help!

Comment: I see you ask a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429345/any-clues-on-how-to-do-this-modular-arithmetic-proof) just about $2$ hours later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$A=2m^3 - 8m^2 + 8n^3 - 12n^2 -10 $$ and $$B= 8m^3 - 12m^2 + 2n^3 - 8n^2 - 10$$

Note that $$A+B = 10 m^3-20m^2+10n^3-20n^2-20 \equiv 0 , \mod (10)$$

So if one of $A$ or $B$ is a multiple of $10$ so is the other.