# Any clues on how to do this modular arithmetic proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

**Assume:**

- $2x^3 - 8x^2 + 8y^3 - 12y^2 -10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$.
- $2y^3 - 8y^2 + 8z^3 - 12z^2 -10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$.

**WTP:**

- $2x^3 - 8x^2 + 8z^3 - 12z^2 -10 \equiv 0 \mod 10$.

I'm not sure where to start. How should I go about this?

Comment: I reckon your first hypothesis says $2x^3+2x^2\equiv 2y^3+2y^2\pmod{10}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown how did you arrive at that, i.e. what were your steps?

Comment: What's $10 \pmod {10}$? And $-8\equiv12\equiv 2 \pmod {10}$.

Comment: @JMP 0, but how do you get from the initial hypothesis to that?

Comment: $\bmod 10\!:\,\ f_3 \equiv f_2 + f_1\equiv 0+0\equiv 0\ \ \ $

Comment: I see you asked a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429279/how-to-approach-this-if-2m3-8m2-8n3-12n2-10-equiv-0-mod-10-then) just about $2$ hours earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing $\pmod {10}$ gives:

$2x^3 +2x^2 - 2y^3 - 2y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$

So:

$2x^3 +2x^2 \equiv 2y^3 + 2y^2  \pmod {10}$

Similarly from eqn. 2 we get:

$2z^3 +2z^2 \equiv 2y^3 + 2y^2  \pmod {10}$

The equivalence relation is transitive, therefore:

$2z^3 +2z^2 \equiv 2x^3 + 2x^2  \pmod {10}$

and so eqn. 3 is true.